# I want to get product of 2 list without using for loop. As with for loop it is taking a lot of time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get product of 2 list without using for loop. As with for loop it is taking a lot of time.

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase,ascii_uppercase
keywords = [a+b+c for a,b,c in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3)]
keywords1 = [a+b for a,b in product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=2)]

for i in keywords:
    for j in keywords1:
        print(i+j)
```

Comment: So what is your question again?

Comment: To get Cartesian product of two list like above keywords and keywords1, but I dont want for loop to be used as it is taking long time.

Comment: I don't think there is a significantly faster way to do that, is this your actual code or just an representative example?

Comment: This is my actual code, as I am trying to get all the combinations of upper case and lower case alphabets.

Comment: There is itertools.combinations also

Comment: You realize `product` uses a loop right? What do you mean by you don't want to use a `for` loop? You can iterate through something without using a loop. You can use NumPy array which can multithread but IDK what you plan to do without a loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the product of the two lists:

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase,ascii_uppercase
keywords = [a+b+c for a,b,c in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat=3)]
keywords1 = [a+b for a,b in product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=2)]

def fast_list():
    return [a+b for a,b in product(keywords,keywords1)]

def med_list():
    return [a+b for a in keywords for b in keywords1]

def slow_list():
    li = []
    for i in keywords:
        for j in keywords1:
            li.append(i+j)
    return li
```

I get that the 'quickest' is `fast_list`, followed by `med_list` followed by `slow_list`:

```
>>> %timeit fast_list()
1.98 s ± 68.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> %timeit med_list()
2.12 s ± 333 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
>>> %timeit slow_list()
2.28 s ± 66.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

However, they are all too close to be definitive -- I would say that they are all about the same time wise. My personal preference is `med_list`, as it uses fewer characters.